# avoiding unnecessary spacing in html tables

Tags: html

In my jsp project i am using tables for ordering my values.
There lot of vertical space is getting wasted in rows, How can I avoid it?
I tried to set padding, margin, etc as 0px. still space is coming.
I am using dream weaver for designing.

```
<table width="742"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" vspace="0">

        <tr onmouseover='over(1)' onmouseout='out()'>
            <td width="113"><h4>F Name 1</h4></td>
            <td width="126"><h4>L Name 1</h4></td>
            <td width="61"><h4>Age 1</h4></td>
            <td width="111"><h4>Gender 1</h4></td>
            <td width="304"><h4>Address 1</h4></td>
        </tr>

        <tr  onmouseover='over(2)' onmouseout='out()'>
            <td ><h4>F Name 2</h4></td>
            <td><h4>L Name 2</h4></td>
            <td><h4>Age 2</h4></td>
            <td><h4>Gender 2</h4></td>
            <td><h4>Address 2</h4></td>
        </tr>

        <tr  onmouseover='over(3)' onmouseout='out()'>
            <td><h4>F Name 3</h4></td>
            <td><h4>L Name 3</h4></td>
            <td><h4>Age 3</h4></td>
            <td><h4>Gender 3</h4></td>
            <td><h4>Address 3</h4></td>
        </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Just stop using `h4` everywhere. Those values aren't headings.

Comment: Use [reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS:

```
h4 { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
table td { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

For those interested, [Mozilla describes border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-collapse) in depth.  In the context of this example:

> In the collapsed border model, adjacent table cells share borders. In
>   that model, the border-style value of inset behaves like groove, and
>   outset behaves like ridge.

Comment: Please explain the use of 
border-collapse: collapse

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove default margins for the h4 tags as well.

```
h4 { margin:0;}
```

All H (h1-h5) tags have built in margins.

Answer (score 3):

There exists some default margin for header tags H1 -H6
put margin=0
for Example
h4 { margin:0;}

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting this stuff in CSS?

```
<style type="text/css">
 .mytable, .mytable td {
   width: 742px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
 H4 {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
</style>
<table class="mytable">

        <tr onmouseover='over(1)' onmouseout='out()'>
            <td width="113"><h4>F Name 1</h4></td>
            <td width="126"><h4>L Name 1</h4></td>
            <td width="61"><h4>Age 1</h4></td>
            <td width="111"><h4>Gender 1</h4></td>
            <td width="304"><h4>Address 1</h4></td>
        </tr>
...
```

Also, you can handle your TD widths and content formatting in CSS, and it will clean up your HTML quite a bit.